# Angular: *ngFor not showing list of components

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm new to Angular/MEAN. I'm following a tutorial, I have no problems there. But now I'm making my own app, and it won't render correctly - I can't figure out what the problem is.

So I've got a model + component 'ENTRY'. I'm trying to display 2 test-entries (created in AppComponent-constructor + put into an Array) in my app, but they are not displayed.

// entry.model.ts

```
import { Segment } from '../segment/segment.model';
import { Marker } from '../marker/marker.model';

export class Entry {
    private _id: string;
    private _title: string;
    private _description: string;
    private _dateCreated: Date = new Date();
    private _dateLastModified;
    private _contents : string;

    constructor(title : string, description : string, contents : string){
        this._title = title;
        this._description = description;
        this._contents = contents;
    }

    public get title() : string {
        return this._title;
    }

    get description() : string {
        return this._description;
    }

    get contents() : string {
        return this._contents;
    }

}
```

// entry.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Entry } from './entry.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry',
  templateUrl: './entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entry.component.css']
})
export class EntryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public entry: Entry;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

// entry.component.html

```
<p>
  This entry is called {{title}}.
  Its description is {{description}}.
  its contents are {{contents}}.
</p>
```

// app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Entry } from './entry/entry.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _entries = new Array<Entry>();

  constructor() {
    const entry1 = new Entry("My Title",
    "This is an overly long description intended as an example, capiche?",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
    this._entries.push(entry1);
    const entry2 = new Entry("My second title",
    "Some other description for testing purposes.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
    this._entries.push(entry2);
  }
}
```

// app.component.html

```
<!-- This one works, in that the html gets rendered but without any properties -->
<app-entry></app-entry>

<!-- All these other ones don't do anything -->
<div *ngFor='let currEntry of entries'>
  <app-entry></app-entry>
</div>
<app-entry *ngFor='let entry of entries'>
  {{entry}}
</app-entry>

<app-entry *ngFor='let currEntry of entries'
[entry]='currEntry'></app-entry>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor='let currEntry of entries'>
      <app-entry [entry]='currEntry'></app-entry>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You're using `_entries` in the component (.ts) and `entries` in the template (.html).

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to edit that. In any case, the problem is still the same... It's not rendering the properties of my tests/examples.

Comment: If you want to render property then write it correctly in **entry.component.html**  `This entry is called {{entry?.title}}.` I use `?` because your first component doesn't pass input.

Comment: @yurzui: that seems to have done the trick... Thank you! So this is necessary because entry.component.ts does not have these fields... So we need the nullable property (is that a thing?) so that the engine continues looking in the model?

Comment: Angular treats `entry?.title` as `entry == null ? null : entry.title`

Comment: @yurzui: so where's the null coming from, if you wouldn't mind explaining?

Comment: initially inputs are not connected (when instantiating)

Answer (score 0):

i guess that in order to access entry input fields(props) from view you should do it like that

```
<p *ngIf="entry" >
  This entry is called {{entry.title}}.
  Its description is {{entry.description}}.
  its contents are {{entry.contents}}.
</p>
```

you also need to change _entries to entry or the other way around in app-component (like user @user184994 pointed out)

edit: added ngIf and it works

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's not really changing anything unfortunately. Well, except that now I only get "This entry is called" and the rest of the paragraph isn't even rendered anymore. If it helps, the github is here: https://github.com/Pieter-JanVanDamme/ScribbleApp

Comment: I've got it on github (https://github.com/Pieter-JanVanDamme/ScribbleApp), does that work for you? Copying fields to the component results in app not rendering anything at all. I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong; I'm almost completely copying my tutorial's example.

Comment: @TheFox Just change `{{entry.title}}` to `{{entry?.title}}` (and make the same change on the other fields). By adding the `?` it won't error if entry is null